# $[0,1]$ is compact regarding the basis $\mathscr{B}=\{\{q\}:q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\}\cup\{]a,b[:0\leqslant a<b\leqslant 1\}\}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Consider $\mathscr{B}=\{\{q\}:q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\}\cup\{]a,b[:0\leqslant a<b\leqslant 1\}\}$
>   Prove that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for the topology $\tau$ in $[0,1]$ and show  $([0,1],\tau)$ is compact.

Proving it is basis of topology I wrote it down on my notebook but it took me a while to deal with all the cases of intersection. I proved the union of all the open sets of the basis equals $[0,1]$ and I intersect two arbitray open sets of the following kind ${q_i}\cup]a_i,b_i[$ and $q_j\cup ]a_j,b_j[$ which gave  me 8 cases. 
When I tried to prove $[0,1]$ to be a compact I thought the basis at [0,1] ,since it would contain the interval and the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, I thoughtit would be the same basis as the Euclidian basis. That would allow me to use Heine-Borel Theorem and finally prove $[0,1]$ is compact.

**Question:**

I am aware my answer is imprecise however it is imprecise as my ideas regarding the problem. I guess it is wrong. 
How should I then solve the exercise?

Comment: Two deeper results: (1).If $(X,\tau) , (X',\tau')$ are compact Hausdorff spaces and if $f:X\to X'$ is a continuous bijection then $f$ is a homeomorphism...(2). Corollary: If $(X,\tau')$ is compact Hausdorff and if $\tau$ is a strictly stronger topology on $X$ then $(X,\tau)$ is not compact . (Proof: $id_X$ is a continuous bijection from $(X,\tau)$ to $(X,\tau')$ because $\tau' \subset \tau,$ so if $ \tau$ is a compact topology then by (1) with $X'=X$ we would have $\tau'=\tau)$....Let $X=[0,1],$ let $\tau'$ be the usual topology on $[0,1]. $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The showing a base part is not very hard: they clearly cover $[0,1]$ and any two basic subsets that intersect have their intersection in the base again (open intervals or singleton rationals). That makes the check pretty easy.

It seems to me that a set like $C=\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \ge 1\}$ is actually closed and discrete in this topology, so that would make the topology non-compact.

It certainly is not the Euclidean topology on $[0,1]$, as it has plenty of isolated points; a dense set of them. It's also not connected for that reason.

Comment: We can also observe that $\{\{0,1\}\}\cup \{(1/n,1): n\in \Bbb N\}$ is an open cover with no finite  sub-cover.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. $C$ is obviously closed in $([0,1],\tau)$. I know there is a theorem that states that every closed set in a compact space is compact. If $C$ was not compact that would be a contradiction hence $([0,1],\tau)$ would be not compact. But I do not really know why $C$ is not compact once ${0}\in[0,1]$ so the sequence and subsequence should converge. What is the reasoning behind the answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PedroGomes it’s a discrete subspace ( all points are rational) and an infinite discrete space is never compact.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing. But I have been thinking about the answer and it has been a little bit hard to accept $C=\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \ge 1\}$ to be closed once each rational number is defined as open on the basis. Is this true?

Comment: @PedroGomes $C$ is also open for that reason. So $[0,1$ is also not connected.

Comment: Thanks for you support! Sorry but for me is not trivial how to prove $C$ is closed. How should one do it?

Comment: @PedroGomes the complement is open ( $\{0\}$ plus countably many disjoint open intervals)